# How to find absolute mininum/maximum of a function on a set?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, absolute-value

I have this function :

$f(x,y)=x²+y²-2y-x$

I want to find the absolute min/max of the function on the set given in the figure below (where L3 is a piece of a circle with center (0, 0).

[image]

I've already describes lines 1 and 2 and found their critical points. Now working with L3 i see on the answer sheet that it is described as

$L3=((x,y): x²+y²=3², −3 ≤ x ≤ 0)$

May I ask you where they are getting the 3² ? I know it may be a dumb question but i just recently started studying the concept of absolute min and max, moreover with coordinates that make it quite harder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula of the circle at origin with radius $r$ is $x^2+y^2=r^2$, here the radius is $3$.

As for the origin problem, you might like to visualize $f$ as

$$x^2+y^2-2y-x=(x-\frac12)^2-\frac14+(y-1)^2-1$$

Comment: Thanks! Grealty appreciate your answer.. One last thing... how do i know the radius is 3?

Comment: $L_3$ is a piece of circle centered at origin, and it passes through $(0,3)$. The distance between $(0,3)$ and $(0,0)$ is $3$.

Comment: Why are you taking into consideration only point (0,3) ? doesn't it also pass through (-3,0)?

Comment: Sure, you can consider that point too, you will find that the distance to origin (the center of the circle) is constant, $3$.

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry last last thing... how come it says on the answer sheet that  we only need to consider the circle for x negative and y positive? (for L3)?

Comment: The circle region is in the second quadrant right? when $x\le 0, y \ge 0$? it doesn't appear in the other quadrants.